# Bootstrap div не вверху страницы

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/app/content/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/app/content/site.css"/>
    <script src="/static/app/scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">
        <select class="custom-select">

            <option value="Apach Karab">Apach Karab</option>

        </select>
        <div class="btn-group pull-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Add freelancer</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove freelancer</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Logout</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="/static/app/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/app/scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/app/scripts/respond.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

И вот что выходит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

div почему то не оказывается вверху. Уже всю голову сломал, что с ним не так?
Юзаю bootstrap 3

Comment: видимых проблем нет, поможет ссылка на вашу страницу, скорее всего что-то с Вашими стилями в `site.css`

Comment: Всё, разобрался. В site.css был прописан сдвиг body на 50 пикселей